# Spring - prevent execution of scheduled method on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I do have a class which does run a cron job of a service every minute which is totally fine.

the service

```
@EnableCaching
@Service
@Qualifier("generalsearchrequests")
public class GeneralSearchCache implements ControlledCacheService {

    private Logger log;

    @Value("${cache.generalsearchrequests.clear}")
    private String clear;

    @Value("${cache.generalsearchrequests.clearintervall.in.milliseconds}")
    private String delayInMs;

    public GeneralSearchCache() {

        super();
        this.log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeneralSearchCache.class);
    }

    public String getKeyPrefix() {

        // general
        return "GSC";
    }

    public static String test(String value) {
        return "coolerprefix" + "_" + value;
    }
    
    public String generateCacheKey(String value) {

        return getKeyPrefix() + "_" + value;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "generalsearchrequests", key = "T(....cache.GeneralSearchCache).test(#key)")
    public String getCacheEntryByKey(String key) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "generalsearchrequests", key = "T(....cache.GeneralSearchCache).test(#key)")
    public void removeCacheEntryByKey(String key) {

    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "generalsearchrequests", key = "T(....smtransformer.cache.GeneralSearchCache).test(#key)")
    public String insertIntoCache(String key, String value) {

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = "generalsearchrequests")

    public void clearCache() {

        System.out.println("Flush Cache " + this.getCacheName() + " " + new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public String getCacheName() {

        return "generalsearchrequests";
    }
}
```

the class which runs the method

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "cache.generalsearchrequests.clear", havingValue = "true")
public class GeneralSearchCacheClearer extends ScheduledCacheClearer {

    @Autowired
    public GeneralSearchCacheClearer(@Qualifier("generalsearchrequests") ControlledCacheService ccs,
        @Value("${cache.generalsearchrequests.clear}") String clear) {
        
        super(ccs, Boolean.valueOf(clear));
    }

    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0-59 * * * *")
    @Autowired
    public void clearCache() {
        System.out.println("CALLING CLEAR CACHE BY GeneralSearchCacheClearer...");
        super.clearCache();
    }

}


public abstract class ScheduledCacheClearer {

    ControlledCacheService ccs;

    boolean clear;

    public ScheduledCacheClearer(ControlledCacheService ccs, boolean clear) {

        this.ccs = ccs;
        this.clear = clear;
    }

    public void clearCache() {

        if (clear) {
            ccs.clearCache();
        }
    }

}
```

the log of the system according to the setting every minute:

```sh
CALLING CLEAR CACHE BY GeneralSearchCacheClearer...
Flush Cache generalsearchrequests Tue Jan 19 16:50:00 CET 2021
2021-01-19 16:50:00.001 TRACE 32327 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor   : Invalidating entire cache for operation Builder[public void -....GeneralSearchCache.clearCache()] caches=[generalsearchrequests] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',true,false on method public abstract void ....ControlledCacheService.clearCache()
```

How do I prevent the execution of the method on application startup?

example logs proving that function of bean will be executed on startup

```sh
2021-01-19 16:46:13.342  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] applicationname   : Starting Application
2021-01-19 16:46:13.342  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] applicationname  : The following profiles are active: ...
2021-01-19 16:46:13.552  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-19 16:46:13.552  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] Http11NioProtocol      : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
2021-01-19 16:46:13.552  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-19 16:46:13.552  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-19 16:46:13.557  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-19 16:46:13.557  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 214 ms
2021-01-19 16:46:13.584 TRACE 32327 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.AnnotationCacheOperationSource   : Adding cacheable method 'getCacheEntryByKey' with attribute: [Builder[public java.lang.String .cache.GeneralSearchCache.getCacheEntryByKey(java.lang.String)] caches=[generalsearchrequests] | key='T(....cache.GeneralSearchCache).test(#key)' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']

2021-01-19 16:46:13.586  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: public void .cachclearer.GeneralSearchCacheClearer.clearCache()

CALLING CLEAR CACHE BY GeneralSearchCacheClearer...

2021-01-19 16:46:13.588 TRACE 32327 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.AnnotationCacheOperationSource   : Adding cacheable method 'clearCache' with attribute: [Builder[public void .cache.GeneralSearchCache.clearCache()] caches=[generalsearchrequests] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='',true,false]
Flush Cache generalsearchrequests Tue Jan 19 16:46:13 CET 2021
```

Comment: Is your problem that @ConditionalOnProperty is not working? Can you doouble check that `cache.generalsearchrequests.clear` is set to false in the context you're having this issue

Comment: the property (cache.generalsearchrequests.clear) is set to true since i do want that GeneralSearchCacheClearer to clear the cache according to the cronjob schedule. sadly the method gets also called by this class on startup of the application as described above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem, according to the message on startup

```sh
2021-01-19 16:46:13.586  INFO 32327 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: public void .cachclearer.GeneralSearchCacheClearer.clearCache()
```

I somehow added the autowired annotation to the clearcache method of the  GeneralSearchCacheClearer class. Removing it will lead to no call of the method on startup anymore.

so I modified the code from the method clearCache from

```
    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0-59 * * * *")
    @Autowired
    public void clearCache() {
        System.out.println("CALLING CLEAR CACHE BY GeneralSearchCacheClearer...");
        super.clearCache();
    }

}
```

to

```
    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0-59 * * * *")
    public void clearCache() {
        System.out.println("CALLING CLEAR CACHE BY GeneralSearchCacheClearer...");
        super.clearCache();
    }
```

which resolves the problem and also removes the info log on startup of the application.

Answer (score 0):

**clearCache**()  only runs **every 1 minute**. At startup it **does not run**. Surely what causes it to be called at the beginning is the logic inside your ScheduledCacheClearer class.

Thanks to ConditionalOnProperty (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty), your GeneralSearchCacheClearer class will only be used if cache.generalsearchrequests.clear = true in your properties (**havingValue** = "**true**").

You can see that in the constructor you pass true as parameter to the base class.
super (ccs, Boolean.valueOf (clear));

Can you check if this class make the call?

Comment: thank you sir, sadly this class does not have any effects / calls on initialisation and only provides the functionality. I added the class to the description of my post